# What is the difference between CSS selectors: element element( div p) vs element>element (div > p)?

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering about CSS selectors. Especially about this one: `"div p"` vs `"div > p"`

Comment: Did you read the docs ? [Descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) VS [Child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator)

Comment: div p selects all p elements which have a div element as an ancestor. div > p selects all p elements which are the direct children of div elements. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Answer (score 0):

`div p`: all elements `<p>` inside `<div>` (including deeply nested elements)

`div > p`: all elements `<p>` which are direct children of `<div>`